# Error variance of FWL estimator (degrees of freedom)

Tags: regression, variance, residuals, linear

I´m having troubles to estimate the error variance of FWL estimator and its degrees of freedom, is this demonstration correct or there is an alternative method to find it? Thanks

\begin{align}
\hat{e}^t & = M_2Y -\ M_2X_1\beta_1\\
& = M_2Y - M_2X_1\ast\ (X_1^tM_2X_1)^{-1}X_1^tM_2Y\\
& = M_2(I - M_2X_1\ast\ (X_1^tM_2X_1)^{-1}X_1^tM_2)Y\\
& = M_2Y - M_2X_1\beta_1\\
& = M_2Y - M_2X_1((X_1^tM_2X_1){-1}X_1^tM_2Y)\\
\hat{e}^t & = Y^tM_2^t - Y^tM_2^tX_1(X_1^tM_2X_1)^{-1}X_1^tM_2^t\\
E\ (\hat{e}^t\hat{e}) & = E(tr(\hat{e}\hat{e}^t))\\
E(tr (\hat{e}\hat{e}^t)) & = E(tr[ M_2Y\ -\ M_2X_1((X_1^tM_2X_1)^-1X_1^tM_2Y)
 \cdot (Y^tM_2^t - Y^tM_2^tX_1(X_1^tM_2X_1)^-1X_1^tM_2^t)]\\
& = tr [M_2YY^tM_2^t\ - M_2YY^tM_2^tX_1(X_1^tM_2X_1)^{-1}X_1^tM_2^t\\
& - M_2X_1((X_1^tM_2X_1)^-1X_1^tM_2YY^tM_2^t\ + M_2X_1((X_1^tM_2X_1)^{-1}X_1^tM_2YY^tM_2^t])\\
& = \sigma^2 [M_2 - 2M_2X_1(X_1^tM_2X_1)^-1X_1^t{M_2}^t - M_2X_1(X_1^tM_2X_1)^-1X_1^tM_2X_1(X_1^tM_2X_1)^-1X_1^tM_2^t]\\
& = \sigma^2 [M_2 - 2M_2X_1(X_1^tM_2X_1)^-1X_1^tM_2^t - M_2X_1(X_1^tM_2X_1)^-1X_1^tM_2^t]\\
& = \sigma^2 [M_2 - M_2X_1(X_1^tM_2X_1)^-1X_1^tM_2^t]
\end{align}

Comment: Are e and ehat the same? How/Why does the expectation disappear?

Comment: I forgot the expected values in the Tr(E(YY^2)). 

\begin{align}
E\ (\hat{e}^t\hat{e}) & = E(tr(\hat{e}\hat{e}^t))\\
E(tr (\hat{e}\hat{e}^t)) & = E(tr[ M_2Y\ -\ M_2X_1((X_1^tM_2X_1)^-1X_1^tM_2Y))
 \cdot (Y^tM_2^t - Y^tM_2^tX_1(X_1^tM_2X_1)^-1X_1^tM_2^t)]\\
& = tr [M_2YY^tM_2^t\ - M_2E(YY^t)M_2^tX_1(X_1^tM_2X_1)^{-1}X_1^tM_2^t\\
& - M_2X_1((X_1^tM_2X_1)^-1X_1^tM_2E(YY^t)M_2^t\ + M_2X_1((X_1^tM_2X_1)^{-1}X_1^tM_2E(YY^t)M_2^t]\\
& = \sigma^2 [M_2 - M_2X_1(X_1^tM_2X_1)^-1X_1^tM_2^t]
\end{align}

Comment: note you can edit your question, so it seems best to integrate these new considerations into the original question